# How to put comma separated string in two different arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, string, explode

I want to put my string (separated by comma) in 2 different arrays.

```
$str = 1,First,2,Second,3,Third,4,Forth,5,Fifth
```

My goal is to group the numbers and the text.

```
$number = {1,2,3,4,5)
$text = {first, second, third, forth, fifth}
```

I tried to use `explode()`, but I only be ale to create a single array.

Comment: Are you sure that there will be always number in first array.

Comment: Show your code/attempt!

Comment: may be use for loop & create array for those at odd and those at even position

Comment: hi @SunilPachlangia, yes first array will always e a number.

Comment: @N.M.N, actually that was my 1st idea, ut unfortunately I dont know how to..

Comment: @khangkhungkhernitz You can accept one of these answers which really helped you as it seems all of these answers are awesome

Answer (score 4):

This should work for you:

First [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) your string by a comma. Then you can [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) the numbers out. And at the end you can simply take the [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) from the `$arr` and the `$numbers` array.

```
<?php

    $str = "1,First,2,Second,3,Third,4,Forth,5,Fifth";
    $arr = explode(",", $str);

    $numbers = array_filter($arr, "intval"); 
    $text = array_diff($arr, $numbers);

?>
```

Comment: It might look simple but it requires to iterate over the array twice. I expect other answers will show a better performance. At least [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30046130/171318) one. Hehe :)

Comment: @hek2mgl I think this would fall under micro-management. I think my code is pretty easy to read and understand.

Comment: @Rizier123 First, I have no issues with this. However, micro-optimization would be to ask if a while is slower than 3 ifs. But if you need to iterate once over an array instead of twice this makes a huge difference. Afar from hello world programs the input will not being that simple like in the example. Let's say it is a file with many lines of input.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `explode()` and `array_map()` over the results:

```
$str = '1,First,2,Second,3,Third,4,Forth,5,Fifth';

array_map(function($item) use (&$numbers, &$strings) {
    if(is_numeric($item)) {
        $numbers []= $item;
    } else {
        $strings []= $item;
    }
}, explode(',', $str));

var_dump($numbers, $strings);
```

Comment: Yeah I really like the way to use `array_map()`

Comment: @Uchiha I suggest to have a look at their friends `array_walk()`, `array_reduce()` and `array_walk_recursive()` as well.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php

$str = array(1,'First',2,'Second',3,'Third',4,'Forth',5,'Fifth');

$letters =array();
$no = array();

for($i=0;$i<count($str);$i++){
  if($i%2 ==0){
    $letters[] = $str[$i];

  }else{
    $no[] = $str[$i];
  }
}
  print_r($no);
  print_r($letters);
?>
```

Comment: Not just me!!someone else also

Comment: My attempt,i had posted;one who asked the question if he wants it let he give upvote!!

Comment: Ok, I missed your comment below the answer. The situation was looking weird, sorry.

Comment: Its ok!!Encourage the attempts also

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you.

```
$str = '1,First,2,Second,3,Third,4,Forth,5,Fifth';
$result = explode(',',$str);
$number = array();
$text = array();
foreach(explode(',',$str) as $key => $value){
    if($key % 2 == 1){
        $text[] = $value;
    }elseif($key % 2 == 0){
        $number[] = $value;
    }
}
print_r($number);//Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 5 )
print_r($text);//Array ( [0] => First [1] => Second [2] => Third [3] => Forth [4] => Fifth )
```

and if your array is not consistent in this manner then some of these above answers are well suited for you like of Rizier123,hek2mgl,& Sunil's one

I'm updating my answer for your correspondent comments over Adrian

```
foreach(explode(',',$str) as $key => $value){
        if(is_numeric($value)){
            $number[] = $value;
        }else{
            $text[] = $value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Great..! No one is considering my answer.. Good One

Answer (score 2):

May be this can help you

```
$str = '1,First,2,Second,3,Third,4,Forth,5,Fifth';

$array = explode(',',$str);

$number = array();
$string = array();


foreach($array as $val)
{
    if(is_numeric($val))
    {
        $number[] = $val;
    }
    elseif(!is_numeric($val))
    {
        $string[] = $val;
    }
}

echo $commNum = implode(',',$number); // These are strings
echo '<br/>'.$commStr = implode(',',$string); // These are strings

echo '<pre>';
print_r($number);  // These are arrays

echo '<pre>';
print_r($string);  // These are arrays
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `explode`, but you need apply some filter in this case is `is_numeric`:

```
<?php

$str = '1,First,2,Second,3,Third,4,Forth,5,Fifth, erewwrw , 6 ';

$array = explode(',', $str);

$array_numbers = array();
$array_letters = array();

for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    if(is_numeric(trim($array[$i]))) {
      $array_numbers[] = trim($array[$i]);  
    } else {
      $array_letters[] = trim($array[$i]);
    }       
}
print_r($array_numbers);
print_r($array_letters);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
)
Array
(
    [0] => First
    [1] => Second
    [2] => Third
    [3] => Forth
    [4] => Fifth
)
```

Comment: If I have $str = '1,First,2,Second,3,Third,4,Forth,5,Fifth,xzcdx,10'; this string

Comment: @AjeetKumar But the string is $str = '1,First,2,Second,3,Third,4,Forth,5,Fifth';

Comment: But you have to give Appropriate result with your code '1,First,2,Second,3,Third,4,Forth,5,Fifth,xzcdx,10'

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your string contains number followed by string and so on,

following should be the solution.

Create two blank arrays: `$numbers` and `$strings`.

Just loop over the array and get even and odd elements.

Even elements should go to numbers array and odd elements should go to strings array.

```
$str = '1,First,2,Second,3,Third,4,Forth,5,Fifth';
$numbers = array();
$strings = array();
$temp = explode(',', $str);
$i=0;
foreach ($temp as $e) {
    if ($i%2) {
        $strings[] = $e;
    }
    else {
        $numbers[] = $e;
    }
    ++$i;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($numbers);
echo '</pre>';

echo '<pre>';
print_r($strings);
echo '</pre>';
```